# PayFlow Pro Sale Transaction Issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to setup my site to accept credit card payment using PayFlow Pro. I am posting a Sale transaction with following data (account details removed) to sandbox (https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com):

PARTNER[6]=&VENDOR[27]=&USER[27]=&PWD[11]=&TRXTYPE[1]=S&TENDER[1]=C&CURRENCY[3]=USD&CREATESECURETOKEN[1]=Y&SECURETOKENID[29]=MySecTokenID-CPVMCKB4TSR0EN3Y&RETURNURL[35]=https://localhost:44387/payment/pay&CANCELURL[35]=https://localhost:44387/payment/pay&ERRORURL[35]=https://localhost:44387/payment/pay&AMT[1]=1&COMMENT1[48]=Name: pankaj negi , StudentID: 14809, TermId:384&ACCT[16]=&EXPDATE[4]=0217&CVV2[4]=&BILLTOFIRSTNAME[6]=pankaj&BILLTOLASTNAME[4]=negi&BILLTOSTREET[18]=15402 Dry Creek Rd&BILLTOCITY[11]=Noblesville&BILLTOSTATE[2]=IN&BILLTOZIP[5]=46060&BILLTOCOUNTRY[2]=US&

And I am getting following response back:
RESULT=0&SECURETOKEN=KDTWfZBwaYEaz5pPUNxJSKQM2&SECURETOKENID=MySecTokenID-CPVMCKB4TSR0EN3Y&RESPMSG=Approved

But this transaction does not show up on Paypal manager. What am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a secure token which will be used to launch the hosted check out page which is Payflowlink.

Remove the following in your request and try and it should work.
CREATESECURETOKEN[1]=Y&SECURETOKENID[29]=MySecTokenID-CPVMCKB4TSR0EN3Y

thanks

Comment: That resolved the issue. Thanks a Ton @MercuryWater. I owe you a drink :)